# Why does saidar and system monitor show different memory usage

Tags: memory

So i noticed that saidar and system monitor show different ram usage,
at least i think it is ram usage. Is not Mem Used ram in saidar??
Is sider a software that can be trusted ?? 
what is it showing at all ??

[image: screen capture]

see 
saidar is showing i am using 1227 mb system monitor 635mb

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two programs just have a different understanding of what they consider used memory. The system monitor considers disk cache unused since it is freed when needed, but Sider does not. They both are correct, just depending on how you define it.

If you don't know what cache I am talking about, it is disk cache used to keep read and written data to/from the disks in memory for easy re-access. It is held by the kernel and is freed for programs that need it within a split second.